# Carousel does not work on my website

Tags: html, css, carousel

**I try run carousel on my website:** http://marekzurek.hekko24.pl/ , under `"Pracuję z najlepszymi`" Code looks fine but carousel doesn't show. Could you take a look at this?

[image]

**AND**

[image]

Comment: Under "Pracuję z najlepszymi" not "Opinie"? I see nothing like on the screen.

Comment: ok see i update your Question with One more image preview .. now can tell what you said ..

Comment: There should be 2 carousels. First one under "Pracuje z najlepszymi" and it doesn't display. Second one under "Opinie" and it works fine. Could you check code of first one?

Comment: okzzz wait.  .. You talking about slider Carousels ...

Comment: I'm talking about this: http://i.imgur.com/undefined.png

Comment: your given img link 404 !!

Answer (score 0):

You must intialise owlcarousel with the second carousel

```
    $(".your-class").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        autoPlay: true,
        navigation: false,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 1],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 1],
        itemsTablet: [768, 1],
        itemsTabletSmall: false,
        itemsMobile: [479, 1],
        pagination: true,
        autoHeight: true,
    });
```